# Event Log "Wake Source" when system wakes from sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows-event-log, wake-on-lan

So I've been troubleshooting sleep timers for our systems and have run across an interesting issue. I need a way to report how long a system was awake after a number of different inputs. Now, I've discovered that the System Log tracks wake and sleep events and even tells you the times that everything happens at. The thing is doesn't tell you is what triggered the wake event. It does give you a numerical code however. Here are some examples of what I am finding.

```
Index              : 2901
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 1
Message            : The system has resumed from sleep.

                     Sleep Time: 2010-10-01T23:20:06.097488100Z
                     Wake Time: 2010-10-03T17:41:12.796400500Z

                     Wake Source: 0
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
Source             : Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
```

--

```
Index              : 2841
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 1
Message            : The system has resumed from sleep.

                     Sleep Time: 2010-10-01T19:19:37.239789600Z
                     Wake Time: 2010-10-01T21:28:48.921200800Z

                     Wake Source: 4HID Keyboard Device
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
Source             : Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
```

So here's my question: Does anyone know what the different numerical codes for the "Wake Source" mean? I think "0" is a magic packet and "4" is a USB device.

Does anyone have any idea if there is any documentation out there on this for Windows 7?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a definitive source for the Wake Source codes, but next time you see a 0, try running the following command at a prompt:

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

it should hopefully give you more information than just a 0.

Comment: While it does give more than just a code, the information is not anything I don't already know. Thanks though